# Transfer ownership of hosting keeping emails and delete them on server

Tags: hosting, web-hosting, shared-hosting

A client of mine is selling his business and he will transfer he's hosting with website and email adresses to the new owner.

My client wants to keep his emails on his computer and delete them on the server before the new owner takes over.

However I'm not sure what is the best approach because there will be backups. My client doesn't want the new owner to have any possibility to read my clients old emails from backups.

What is the best approach, is there any differences if the emails are setup for POP3 or IMAP ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following are difference between POP3 and IMAP

1] POP3 -if you are keeping this option while configuring your email client,then it will directly download email from server and there will be no email copy on server once it is downloaded.

2] IMAP -if email client is configured with IMAP then it will shows just header of an email and once we click on it, it will download email from server. Copy of email will be there on server after download even.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.